# Files not uploading in Django form

Tags: python, django

So I've got a model with several fields, two of them being a `photo` and a `video` field. They are both of type `FileField`. I've already made a form before using the `FileField` type and everything worked correctly, but for some reason this time it is not. The `settings.py` is configured correctly, because I can upload a file through another form.

I can go into the Django admin and from there add an image and video for the `photo` and `video` field and the new directory is made and the image and video is stored and can be accessed with no problem. I'm a little stumped on this one. Thanks in advance.

Here is my model:

```
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('images', str(instance.id), filename)

def get_video_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('videos', str(instance.id), filename)

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to=get_video_path, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name + ' - ' + self.email
```

Here is my form, which is a `ModelForm`:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

And here is the view:

```
def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    pollform = PollForm()
    choiceform = ChoiceForm()
    userform = UserForm()
    all_users = User.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pollform = PollForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        choiceform = ChoiceForm(request.POST)
        userform = UserForm(request.POST)
        if pollform.is_valid():
            pollform.comments = pollform.cleaned_data['comments']
            pollform.save()
        else:
            pollform = PollForm()
        if choiceform.is_valid():
            choiceform.save()
        else:
            choiceform = ChoiceForm()
        if userform.is_valid():
            userform.save()
        else:
            userform = UserForm()
    context = {'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list, 'pollform': pollform,
           'choiceform': choiceform, 'userform': userform, 'all_users': all_users}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

Here is the form associated with the `ModelForm`:

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:index' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ userform.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as an attribute in your `form` tag.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <your form code>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other answers (i.e. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680770/django-imagefield-not-working-properly-via-modelform)) indicate you need to pass `request.FILES` to your Form if you're using a FileField. Is this your problem?

I.e. change this line:

```
userform = UserForm(request.POST)
```

to:

```
userform = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

EDIT:

Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads).